# Price_unit readonly workaround onchange

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

So my goal is to make price_unit in sale order line read-only field. But when you do this you have a problem with onchange method so if I just add attributes read-only price_unit after write always gets to 0.

So as workaround I made onchange method to store price_unit values and then add them to price_unit in write and create method.

But vals in write method don't have price_unit_values but at the same time, my onchange method added them to the price_unit_values earlier.

And I'm getting this error

```
 if vals['price_unit_values']:
    KeyError: 'price_unit_values'
```

```xml
 <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field/tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="attributes">
                     <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
    </xpath>
```

```py
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.line"

    price_unit_values = fields.Float(string='Price Unit Values', digits=(6, 2), required=False)

@api.onchange('price_unit')
    def _onchange_price_unit(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.price_unit:
                rec.price_unit_values = rec.price_unit


@api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
         if vals['price_unit_values']:
             vals['price_unit'] = vals['price_unit_values']
        return super(SaleOrderLine, self).write(vals)

 @api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals['price_unit_values']:
        vals['price_unit'] = vals['price_unit_values']
    rec = super(SaleOrderLine, self).create(vals)
    return rec
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/8.0/web_readonly_bypass) is helpful ;-)

Comment: Yeh I know about this module, but not an option for me unfortunately :/